# JQuery how to fire all child onmouseover elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

The code bellow does the following: when the user hovers the links, it triggers the titles(text) with a css(text+background) position on background image. But there is a visibility problem when that happens. In order for the user to see the onmouseover spam titles, the user has to go all over the image until it finds the onmouseover trigger to see the title(text).

What I want to achieve is: when the user hovers on any part of the background image it will trigger all onmouseover events inside the same div.Unfortunately I am struggling in find a solution for it.

Here is the JSFIDDLE : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nfsarmento/2exuv1pd/)

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

 $j(document).ready(function(){

   $j( 'a' ).mouseout(function(){
     var book_id=$j(this).parent().attr('id');

     $j('#'+book_id).children('.info_span1').hide();
     $j('#'+book_id).children('.info_span2').hide();
   });

   $j('a').mouseenter(function(){
   var book_id=$j(this).parent().attr('id');
   var position = $j(this).position();
   $j('#'+book_id).children('.info_span1').show();
   $j('#'+book_id).children('.info_span2').show();


   $j('#'+book_id).children('.info_span1').text($j(this).data("title1"));
   $j('#'+book_id).children('.info_span2').text($j(this).data("title2"));
   $j('#'+book_id).children('.info_span1').css({top: $j(this).height()-6, left:position.left, position:'absolute'});
   $j('#'+book_id).children('.info_span2').css({top: $j(this).height()-6, left:position.left+$j(this).width(), position:'absolute'});

  });
});
```

HERE IS THE SOLUTION : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashant05/944pobqk/)

Comment: java has nothing to do with javascript ;)

Comment: To speed up your code you should cache a reference to the elements you're querying with jQuery in a variable. For example, `var $book = $j('#'+book_id);` instead of always querying with `$j('#'+book_id)` to access the element. You could also do this in your `mouseenter` function when accessing child elements, `var $info1 = $book.children('.info_span1');`. Also do it when you need to pass `this` to jQuery, `var $this = $(this);` then `$this.data()` or `$this.height()`.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie is not impossible and here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/prashant05/944pobqk/2/

Comment: @CabLondon: Good effort. Appending new tooltips for each link dynamically. Just clean up all the other coding issues and you have the answer :)